# Could I implement MakeHuman into a UE4 game as a character creator?

Tags: unreal-4

Would it be possible to take MakeHuman and put it into a game made in Unreal Engine as a character creator?

Of course many unnecessary features would have to be removed, but would it work at all, and would it be easier than making such a system from scratch? MakeHuman is open source so there shouldn't be any legal issues.

Comment: "General Public Licenses are intended to guarantee your freedom to share and change all versions of a program--to make sure it remains free software for all its users." - gnu.org,  aka: your game must remain open source

Comment: But other than that, you're technically allowed to use it: "...you can change the software or use pieces of it in new free programs, and that you know you can do these things" - gnu.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically speaking, no.

MakeHuman is a decently large, complex code base **written in Python** against particular specific UI APIs and conventions. Unreal is a very large, complex code base **written in C++** against completely different UI APIs and conventions. It would probably be extremely difficult to "integrate" MakeHuman into Unreal as a runtime character generator. Prohibitively so.

You'd almost certainly have an easier time building your own runtime character generator directly inside Unreal.

Further, just because MakeHuman is open-source doesn't mean there will be no legal issues. [MakeHuman is released under a specific license (AGPL)](https://bitbucket.org/MakeHuman/makehuman/) which imposes certain requirements on its use. Your intended use may violate those requirements, and the license for MakeHuman may also conflict in various interesting and subtle ways with the license for Unreal. You'd want to double-check the licensing very carefully, possibly getting a lawyer to review it and your intended use.

Comment: i see, and are there any other premade character creation systems that would work with unreal engine?

Comment: None that I know of offhand. You might try asking about that at [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net) because that sort of question is off-topic here, I'm afraid.